# Making two bots count each other's messages

Tags: python, discord, bots

So, as a holiday project, I'm trying to make two bots who reply to the other's messages. They'll check the ID of the sender and if it matches the ID of the other bot, it will send a message with the number of times that bot has replied.

The problem is that when I try to execute this, both bots send two messages and the count does not go higher than 1.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import time

TOKEN = #BOT TOKEN#
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    tally = 0
    if message.author.id == 887901692673261618:
        tally += 1
        time.sleep(5)
        await message.channel.send(tally)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I've tried defining the tally variable underneath the TOKEN and client definition but it then says tally referenced before assignment

Comment: `tally` is set to 0 on every invocation of `on_message`. Store this count as a global variable and don't set it to zero in this method?

Answer (score 0):

In every message, you are setting the tally variable to 0. This is resetting the counter and thus it doesn't increase

About the variable being referenced before assignment, you should define it above the function for clarity. Defining it anywhere **before** `client.run` is gonna work, but not **after** `client.run` since `client.run` blocks the code from going any further unless the bot is stopped, so your variable is being defined after you close the bot not while it's running therefore the error. Now

- You can use the global keyword to modify the value of a variable defined outside the function
- You can set tally to be an attribute of the client, this would remove the need of using the global keyword

Example of setting it as an attribute of `client`

```py
import discord
import time

TOKEN = #BOT TOKEN#
client = discord.Client()
client.tally = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.id == 887901692673261618:
        client.tally += 1
        time.sleep(5)
        await message.channel.send(client.tally)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Example of setting it as a global variable

```py
import discord
import time

TOKEN = #BOT TOKEN#
client = discord.Client()
tally = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global tally
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.id == 887901692673261618:
        tally += 1
        time.sleep(5)
        await message.channel.send(tally)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Consider learning more about variable scopes in python